# currentPosition never seems to leave 1?

Tags: javascript

Im have written a small function that basically takes the currentPosition value as a parameter works out if that number is equal to the overall number of slides and if it isnt adds 1 to the value, unfortunately though my incremented number never seems to move from 1. Can anyone advise me where I may be going wrong?

```
var currentPosition = 0;
            var slideWidth = 320;
            var numberOfSlides = sliderSlides.children.length;
            console.log('Number of slides = ', numberOfSlides);

            //Remove scrollbar in js
            sliderCtn.style.overflow = 'hidden';  

            //Set .slides width equal to total width of all slides
            sliderSlides.style.width = slideWidth * numberOfSlides + 'px';                      

            // Direction click handlers
            sliderDirNext[det.clickEvent] = function(e) {               
                next(currentPosition);
                sliderSlides.style.left = slideWidth*(-currentPosition) + 'px';         
                console.log('Slide width ', slideWidth);
                stopEvent(e);
            };

 function next(currentPosition){
                    if( currentPosition === numberOfSlides ) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        currentPosition += 1;
                        console.log('Next current position = ', currentPosition);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: `currenPosition` is passed by value rather than by reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution. ***Though, there is most likely a better one if you provide more context***:

```
window.currentPosition = 0;

function next(){
    if( currentPosition === numberOfSlides ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        currentPosition += 1;
        console.log('Next current position = ', currentPosition);
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

**After OP Update**:

Simply removing the `next` function `currentPosition` parameter should resolve your issue, given the rest of your logic is sound.

Comment: thanks Xander, sorry Im just not completely sure when a parameter is required and when it isnt

Answer (score 1):

The value of your parameter is never incremented outside of the function because primitives are passed by value and not by reference.

To solve your problem you could make your function return a boolean and increment the value if the function returned true:

```
if (next(currentPosition))
    ++currentPosition;
```

Or you could get rid of the function and just put the code inline.

Answer (score 1):

You are just incrementing your local copy of the variable (within the function scope). So the next call to `next` gets a new copy of your original variable and starts all over again.

To have a real counter, you may introduce a global variable (within some namespace possibly), which you then modify in the function, like

```
var slider = {
  curPos: 0,
  next: function() {
    if( this.curPos === numberOfSlides ) {
      return false;
    } else {
      this.curPos += 1;
      console.log('Next current position = ', this.curPos );
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Another possibilty would be to use a closure for this.

```
function getCounter() {
  var curPos = 1;
  return function() {
        if( curPos === numberOfSlides ) {
          return false;
        } else {
          curPos += 1;
          console.log('Next current position = ', curPos );
          return true;
        }
  };
}

var next = getCounter();
next();
```